# Files containing information regarding the scheduler, task tracker and job tracker communication

Tags: xml, hadoop

Which are the files from the hadoop source code that can be viewed to get a better understanding of the communication between scheduler, jobtracker and tasktracker ?

Answer (score 1):

You may look into following classes and then explore as you read through:

- [JobTracker](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker.java#JobTracker)
- [TaskScheduler](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskScheduler.java)
- [TaskTracker](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskTracker.java#TaskTracker)
- [TaskScheduler](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskScheduler.java#TaskScheduler)
- [TaskTrackerManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskTrackerManager.java#TaskTrackerManager)